# Is it possible to send information from web server to client with out request?

Tags: http

HTTP is a request-reply type protocol. Is it possible to send information from the server to client with out the client explicitly making the request ? If, possible, then how can the client *listen* that information ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

yes there is a way. its called websockets.

look here for some nice examples:

http://www.websocket.org/demos.html